# React native scrollView not wrapping text elements (showing in a row) properly

Tags: react-native, scrollview

[image]I am using scrollView in need to show multiple text elements () in a single row.
For that i am using something like

`
        
            {':AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:'}
            {':BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB:'}

I am getting result something shown in image. Second  'BB.....' is not wrapping properly.
`

[image]

Comment: What's your problem ? "B" line go outside the screen ?

Comment: Yes B line is going outside the line. That is my problem

Comment: use `flexShrink:1` on `View` or `flexWrap: 'wrap'`

Answer (score 0):

add flexwrap to view

Like this

```
<View
    style={{
      flexDirection: 'row',
      flexWrap: 'wrap'
    }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting the two texts inside a container Text:

```
<Text>
    <Text>A...</Text>
    <Text>B...</Text>
</Text>
```